# best mysql configuration file's variable for 2GB DB

Tags: mysql, database, my.cnf

I have a 2GB DB and it is very slow below my configuration file variable , what I shall change to make it faster

```
read_buffer_size=1M
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
sort_buffer_size=256K
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=2M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=1M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=16M
innodb_log_file_size=10M
innodb_thread_concurrency=8
max_connections=151
old_passwords=0
max_user_connections=30
thread_cache_size=4
thread_stack=196608
binlog_cache_size=32768
net_read_timeout=30
net_retry_count=10
net_write_timeout=30
thread_concurrency=10
open_files_limit=4161
table_definition_cache=400
```

---

```
Threads_cached  2
Threads_connected   2
Threads_created     12
Threads_running     1
```

Comment: How much RAM does you server have?  # CPU's?  Please post results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'threads_%';  and SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%connect%;   If you will remove  read_buffer_size from your configuration, you will quit forcing a read of 1M data when 128K (the default) would be fine.

Comment: I made edit to the post please review

Comment: This question is not about a specific programming issue. I'm voting to move it to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Repeat of request for information. 1. How much RAM does your server have?  2, # CPU's?  3. Please post results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%connect%';.  4. From the thread information provided, suggest you change configuration to thread_cache_size = 20 to support more than the 12 threads_created.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I'll just leave the rest alone and only adjust:

1. innodb_buffer_pool_size to around 70~80% or your 2GB, in this case 1.6G
2. innodb_log_file_size to half of above, in this case 800M
3. max_connections depends on your application, normally I'll set it to at least 200.

But "slow" is very general and it may be impacted by your logic/structure as well.

Comment: We do not know how much RAM this person is running.  He indicated 
'I have a 2GB DB'.  We need more information, please.